# Editing donation fields

Tags: donations

I'm trying to edit the 'If other, please specify' line on our donation form. I'm very new to this position and can't find an answer through my own searching.

Comment: Welcome Allie! That line doesn't appear by default, so we can't know where that line appears without a screenshot or a link to the donation form. Please edit your question to include one or the other and someone can try to help!

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking if your page uses a Price Set and then investigating the issue there. Otherwise it might be a field in a Profile, and that text may either be in the field 'pre help' or in the Profile 'pre or post help'

Comment: Ours is under Administer > Custom Data and Screens > Profiles Then click on Fields to the right of the Profile that goes with it, Click on Edit and you will see the Pre Help/Post Help